# get row and column of matrix

Tags: python

I wonder where how to get row and column of this matrix. I want to loop through each element[row][column], but I have no idea how to get these.

```
imaginary_axis = 100
real_axis = 1

mixed_matrix = [[0 for j in xrange(imaginary_axis)] for i in xrange(real_axis)]

for row in mixed_matrix[0]:
    print(row)
    for column in mixed_matrix:
         print(column)
         check(mixed_matrix[row][column])
```

This throws an error. How can I get this to work?

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

I know why I get this error, but I do not know how I can get the column right.

Comment: "throws an error"? surely you can do better than that

Comment: Look at it like this, you iterate `mixed_matrix[0]` which is a list, so in that case your 'row' will be an integer or whatever the contents of that list is.

Then you iterate mixed_matrix itself, which will make your `column` be a list of lists.

What you (probably) want to do is iterate like:
`for row in range(0, len(mixed_matrix[0]))` and do the same with your column for loop but making use of the row index i.e.
`for column in range(0, len(mixed_matrix[0][row]))`

I might have gotten this totally wrong, but that's my take on it.

Comment: That wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you can use smth like [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Cause in your example your `column` is a list, but as i can see - you want the number of element in this list.

I edit my answer:

What do you want? Magic? There is no magic. You have matrix, like this:
[[1, 2, 3]]

There is a list inside list. 
You want to iterate by elements?

`for lst in matrix:
      for element in lst:
              print(element)`

Or you can zip your lists in ONE list and iterate by element in that list.

If you want access by index - you should use it.
You should have two loops, the number of your lists is the number of rows, the number of your elements in list - is number of columns.

And you need smth lile:

```
for row in range(0, len(mixed_matrix)):
   # mixed_matrix[row] - is your FIRST list
   for column in range(0, len(mixed_matrix[row])):
    print(mixed_matrix[row][column])
```

Comment: How exactly? IS there not an easier way?

Comment: column is a index position of inserted list?

`for row in mixed_matrix[0]:
    print(row)
    for column, list in enumerate(mixed_matrix):
        print(column)
        print(mixed_matrix[row][column])`

Comment: Please, see my answer, i edit it, cause my anseer is too long

Answer (score 0):

These days we use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to get row x column of a given matrix

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[56.0, 0.0 , 4.4, 68.0], 
         [1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0],
         [1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9]])
print(A.shape)
```

Will out put (3, 4) 3 rows, 4 columns